# Aplicação Modular Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Estou começando a trabalhar com aplicações modulares no `DelphiXE3`, no entanto não estou encontrando muita coisa a respeito.

Pegando uma coisinha dali de daqui, criei uma dll com um `form` e o adicionei à uma DLL. Minha dúvida agora é a seguinte: Como faço pra chamar esse `form`da minha aplicação principal?

A princípio estou fazendo apenas alguns teste, assim que conseguir entender o conceito da modularização, tenho um projeto inteiro para tornar modular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A melhor forma de modularizar uma aplicação Delphi é por meio de **packages**, não DLLs. **Packages** são na verdade DLLs, mas eles carregam informação de tipagem rica (o que não é o caso de uma DLL), que é precisamente o que vai te permitir criar um executável e dele carregar objetos existentes nestes **packages**.

Comment: E como eu carregaria um **Package** em minha aplicação, e como abrir um form desse **Package**?

Comment: Os métodos LoadPackage e UnloadPackage podem ser usados quando o programador opta por ter este tipo de trabalho, mas normalmente não é o caso. Um aplicativo Delphi pode ser construído com o que se chama **runtime packages**, onde o processo de fazer a carga e as ligações é totalmente automático. Procure referências a respeito de **runtime packages**.

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada e achei alguns materiais a respeito e já comecei a modular o meu sistema. 
No entanto surgiu outra dúvida. Em uma **Unit** que ficará em um dos módulos, possuo:

`type
  TUsuario = record
    id:Integer;
    idEmpresa:Integer;
    usuario:string;
    foto:string;
    validade: TDateTime;
    senha:string;
    nome:string;
    admin:Boolean;
    ultimoAcesso:TDateTime;
    dataCadastro:TDateTime;
  end;`

e

`var
  usuario:TUsuario;`

Que em determinados momentos vou alimentar essa variável e em outros vou recuperar as informações dela.

Minha dúvida: Como fazer isso?

Comment: @ThiagoThaison para cada dúvida tente utilizar uma pergunta diferente. Evite perguntas em cascata.

Comment: Ok, Obrigado...

Comment: @ThiagoThaison: por favor, se você considerou a minha resposta apropriada, marque a questão como respondida